# CRUD performance - job interview question

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, data-structures

Real job interview question, asked by some 'top level' engineer. Truly saying, I think this is question about finding 'holy grail' of data structures. But I'm trying to understand how to respond on such kind of 'questions'.

Asked:
We have
Get(id), Put(id, model), Delete(id), Add(id, model) operations in service interface.

There is service S satisfying interface. It stores data in some container/collection.

1. What is the way to make these operations to perform with efficiency O(1)?
2. At the same time this container/collection should use minimum memory.
   Let's imagine we talk about c# or Javascript/typescript here.

Comment: Be aware that `Map` (JavaScript) = `Dictionary<K, V>` (.NET) = the general concept of a hashmap exists, I guess?

Comment: I would be reasonably sure they are talking about hashtables / hashmaps. In terms of minimum memory - that is very hard to answer without more domain knowledge (e.g. what does `model` look like?). The memory statement is _probably_ just to make you say `hashtable` rather than `array` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_data_structure .

Comment: You may want to read a book like https://www.amazon.com/Cracking-Coding-Interview-Programming-Questions/dp/0984782850 … if you can't answer "what to use to get O(1) lookup by ID" as part of interview reading that particular book will give you stock answers (plus basic framework on answering questions). I'm not exactly sure what you expect as answer to #2 here (which is roughly "let's chat about data structures" and does not in any way fit into SO Q&A format)

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad. The "minimum memory" and O(1) requirements are pretty vague. Can we store just the keys in memory, and the actual data on disk? That would fit the requirement.

Comment: You can close, I just wanted to see how others would react on weird question. I see most of responses are similar to my answers, thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about #2, but for #1, a Javascript object is actually a hashmap, so lookups run in O(1) time. You could simply use an object whose keys represent primary keys identifying entries in our datastore. The value of each key is the entry itself.

Answer (score 0):

> Asked: We have Get(id), Put(id, model), Delete(id), Add(id, model) operations in service interface.

O(1) in TypeScript `Map<Key,Value>` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map